# setOnclickListener vs Activity implements View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to implement `OnClick` behaviour on my application view. As I am new to android and will like to know if passing this to while implementing `View.OnClickListener` interface will be better choice or using `setOnclickListener` Anonymous class to widget. As to me what I feel is that passing this may cause the whole activity and its child elements to the particular widget so having more memory consumption and so to avoid memory leak which is the best approach to go with.

Comment: Best choice is to implement View.OnClickListener. it will reduce some lines of code and easy to keep all click event in one block.

Comment: @Nas yup I know this but I am curious about memory consumption.

Comment: Probably It will reduce some memory(space) in your file size, However both will refer to the same class and will work identically so it allocate same amount  of memory(RAM).

Answer (score 1):

Actually when we implement OnClickListener because we have more than one or two click item. like if i have 10 buttons in a single layout and i write each click listener as:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
  button2setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
  button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Its not a good programming practice thats why we implement OnClickListener and write all the click listeners in onClick().
so it looks easy to you for making any changes in future.

else if you have single button then you can use setOnClickListener().

There is not too much difference between these two. Its all about good coding practice in android. :)

Comment: Its all ok but I think implementing an interface and then passing using this means we are creating a whole reference of the activity to the particular widget so possibly duplicating all the memory overheads associated with the activity. while in passing interface as an anonymous class we are just passing the particular interface not the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
android:onClick = "ButtonOne"
```

attribute in xml file.its easy !!

Comment: I am not asking for what is easy I'm just thinking about it in another perspective that is memory management.

Comment: AFAIK all the three approaches uses the almost same memory. The matter to be consider is, which one is the good coding practice.It depends on the situations. implementing View.OnClickListener and using android:onClick = "ButtonOne" are preferable then using setOnClickListner for each buttons, in my opinion.